# Using regex_search to extract a string between a string and a whitespace

Tags: regex, ansible, regex-group

I would like to extract the version number  `1.0.1` from the following string in Ansible, I tried using regex_serach to extra the string between `ide-` and a whitespace, but that's what I end up getting `ide-1.0.1 ; argv[]=/home/bin/ide-1.0.1 start`. I tried `\s` instead of `\\s` and it doesn't work. How should I fix the regex pattern? Any help would be appreciated!

```
ExecStart={ path=/home/bin/ide-1.0.1 ; argv[]=/home/bin/ide-1.0.1 start }
```

```
- name: Check if ide is active
  command: systemctl show ide.service --property=ExecStart
  register: version_check
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: Set fact
  set_fact:
    version: "{{ version_check.stdout | regex_search('ide-(.*)\\s'}}"


- name: Debug version
  debug:{{ version }}"
```

Comment: `regex_search('ide-([^ ]+).*','\\1')` should be enough!

Answer (score 0):

Use *regex_replace*, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        version: "{{ _path.split('-').1 }}"
      vars:
        _regex: '^(.*)=(.*)=(.*);(.*)$'
        _replace: '\3'
        _path: "{{ version_check.stdout|regex_replace(_regex, _replace)|trim }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  version: 1.0.1
```

---

[Parsing semi-structured text with Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/user_guide/cli_parsing.html#parsing-semi-structured-text-with-ansible) is available, e.g.

```yaml
    - ansible.utils.cli_parse:
        text: "{{ version_check.stdout }}"
        parser:
          name: ansible.netcommon.native
          template_path: templates/property.yaml
        set_fact: property
```

and the template

```yaml
shell> cat templates/property.yaml
---
- example: 'ExecStart={ path=/home/bin/ide-1.0.1 ; argv[]=/home/bin/ide-1.0.1 start }'
  getval: '(?P<property>\S+)={\s*(?P<key1>\S+)=(?P<val1>\S+)\s*;\s*(?P<key2>\S+)=(?P<val2>\S+)\s*(?P<state>\S+)\s*}'
  result:
    "{{ property }}":
      "{{ key1 }}": "{{ val1 }}"
      "{{ key2 }}": "{{ val2 }}"
      state: "{{ state }}"
```

give

```yaml
  property:
    ExecStart:
      argv[]: /home/bin/ide-1.0.1
      path: /home/bin/ide-1.0.1
      state: start
```

Then parse the version, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        version: "{{ (property.ExecStart.path|basename).split('-').1 }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  version: 1.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is it possible to do this simply by regex_research instead?